# Clean install OSX 10.9.1 returns "undefined method `path2class'" when trying to install gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler, psych

I just installed a clean Mavericks installation with Homebrew and RVM. Both `brew doctor` and `rvm requirements` return "all good", however, when I run `bundle install` in my project dir most of my gems install fine, but a handful fail to install with the same following error:

```
Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem at /Users/NK/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/cache/eventmachine-1.0.3.gem. It may be corrupted.
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Then, if I try again with `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.3'` I get:

```
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
    invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `path2class' for #<Psych::ClassLoader:0x000001018f7990> (NoMethodError) in /Users/NK/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/cache/eventmachine-1.0.3.gem
```

I tried to implode RVM and reinstall, but nothing helps.

Other people seem to have the same problem, but no one seems to have fund the answer yet:

- http://pastebin.com/LV53GdR2
- [Install Rails Error "invalid gem: package is corrupt"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850737/install-rails-error-invalid-gem-package-is-corrupt)
- [Error install rubyracer with error "invalid gem: package is corrupt"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888318/error-install-rubyracer-with-error-invalid-gem-package-is-corrupt)

**EDIT**

See those two as well:

- https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/issues/182
- https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2620

Comment: I got the same issue, it seems that there's something wrong with the latest release of Psych, one the default Ruby gems.

Comment: Have you tried deleting that path?

Comment: did you try installing different psych versions?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It turns out that this is a bug in an older version of psych, but it can't be solved, as long as you installed ruby with RVMs statically linked gems. So basically the problem is related to RVMs statically linked gems. Installing rubies with the `--disable-binary` solves the problem:

```
rvm install 2.0.0-p353 --disable-binary
```

Or reinstall with:

```
rvm reinstall 2.0.0-p353 --disable-binary
```

Comment: I may have had other problems, but when I did this it didn't work at first. So I did _rvm implode_ first (removes all traces of rvm, ruby, gems, etc), then an install with --disable-binary fixed the problem.

Comment: This solution worked for me, however, I discovered later on a colleagues computer that uninstalling psych also works. Since psych is included in MRI, our gems that are dependent on psych still work.

Answer (score 22):

I had the very same error and looked into the psych gem

```
$ gem list --local | grep psych
psych (2.0.4, 2.0.0)
```

as version 2.0.4 was recently installed I removed it, keeping only version 2.0.0

```
$ gem uninstall psych -v '2.0.4'
Successfully uninstalled psych-2.0.4
```

After that, everything worked fine again!

Comment: Using an old version of psych kind of works, but I was looking for a solution, not a workaround. Thanks anyway!

Comment: This will not work if ruby was installed with static links using RVM (see accepted answer)

Comment: Sorry, this was only meant as a workaround, thanks for the solution & explanation @NielsKristian!

Answer (score 2):

**Immediate Cause**

`psych.so` is not located at the proper location.

**Solution/Workaround**

In my case,

```
cp /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/psych-2.0.13/lib/psych.so \
   /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/
```

**Details**

`path2class` method is defined in `psych_to_ruby.c` and registered into `Psych::ClassLoader` class as a private method by `rb_define_private_method()`. The following is the code. Take a look at the last line of `Init_psych_to_ruby()` function.

```c
static VALUE path2class(VALUE self, VALUE path)
{
#ifdef HAVE_RUBY_ENCODING_H
    return rb_path_to_class(path);
#else
    return rb_path2class(StringValuePtr(path));
#endif
}

void Init_psych_to_ruby(void)
{
    VALUE psych     = rb_define_module("Psych");
    VALUE class_loader  = rb_define_class_under(psych, "ClassLoader", rb_cObject);

    VALUE visitors  = rb_define_module_under(psych, "Visitors");
    VALUE visitor   = rb_define_class_under(visitors, "Visitor", rb_cObject);
    cPsychVisitorsToRuby = rb_define_class_under(visitors, "ToRuby", visitor);

    rb_define_private_method(cPsychVisitorsToRuby, "build_exception", build_exception, 2);
    rb_define_private_method(class_loader, "path2class", path2class, 1);
}
```

`Init_psych_to_ruby()` is called from `Init_psych()` function, which is defined in `psych.c`.

```c
void Init_psych(void)
{
    mPsych = rb_define_module("Psych");

    rb_define_singleton_method(mPsych, "libyaml_version", libyaml_version, 0);

    Init_psych_parser();
    Init_psych_emitter();
    Init_psych_to_ruby();
    Init_psych_yaml_tree();
}
```

Ruby calls `Init_{library}()` function after it loads the library's shared library (.so file). So, in the case of psych, if `psych.so` is found and loaded, `Init_psych()` function is called and in turn `Init_psych_to_ruby()` is called, and finally `path2class` is registered. However, if `psych.so` does not exist, `path2class` is never registered and you will see the error message *"undefined method `path2class'"*.

Probably, there is something wrong in the packaging process of either psych or Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and remembered that XCode had been updated recently. I was reminded of this because some Terminal output claimed that the developer tools were not installed and suggested running the following:

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

It still wasn't working so I used rvm to install the latest 2.1 version of Ruby, created a new gemset, pointed my app to use that gemset and ran `$ bundle install`. It now works.

Answer (score 0):

For me this turned out to be a permissions issue. I fixed it by resetting my permissions on my `~/.rvm` folder. Mac OS X 10.9.3.

First, find your system username:

```
ls -lA ~ | head
```

Produces:

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 nperry  staff   43012 Jul  1 13:25 .DS_Store
drwx------  63 nperry  staff    2142 Jul  1 13:40 .Trash
...
```

My username is `nperry` and my group is `staff`. Change the following lines to match your user and group.

```
sudo chown -R nperry:staff  ~/.rvm
sudo chmod -R ug+rw ~/.rvm
```

And no more errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a particularly insightful answer, but in my case the problem went away by switching to `ruby-2.1.2` (p95, incidentally) via `rvm`.

I was going to upgrade anyway...