# "gem install rails" fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I run

```
gem install rails
```

I get

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/cache/nokogiri-1.6.7.rc3.gem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error message says the "package is corrupt", you need to find a way to delete it and download it again.

Google "rails package is corrupt" and you will find some links to stackoverflow with similar queries. For example: [Error install rubyracer with error "invalid gem: package is corrupt"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888318/error-install-rubyracer-with-error-invalid-gem-package-is-corrupt)

Another similar problem: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14807

Comment: I deleted  the file mentioned in the error. There was a few dependency issues, but I was able to install it after that.Thanks!!

Comment: I suggest upgrading your Rails version if possible. That might help to avoid future conflicts of this sort.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on version of Ruby that you are using. I know that 2.2.* versions has conflicts with Nokogiri. I switched to 2.1.* versions which works fine with Nokogiri.

Comment: Mine is 2.1.*
 "ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux-gnu]"

Answer (score -1):

Try to install Nokogiri first using

```
# gem install nokogiri
```

And after that install Rails

```
# gem install rails
```